# Multiple IP addresses added on the same network goes down after some time

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, network-interface

I have two raspberrys pi running on a remote location. Both of them are configured with a primary IP address that can connect to the internet.

I needed to be able to reach other local network destinations at the same time, so what I did was create new IP assigns for the same network adapter.

It works well, but after a while one of the boards loses connection to the other address. I can still connect to it via remote SSH using the primary IP assigned to it for internet connection, but the other address are unreachable until I reboot the board.

I only acknowledge this behaviour in one of them, the other seems to keep it's connections.

Here is the return of the command `ip addr`

```
1: lo: mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default

link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000

link/ether b8:27:eb:0a:ec:fe brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 125.125.10.31/24 brd 125.125.10.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

inet 192.168.60.101/21 brd 192.168.63.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

inet 10.10.1.200/21 brd 10.10.7.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

inet 10.10.3.170/21 brd 10.10.7.255 scope global secondary eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe0a:ecfe/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Route information

```
default via 125.125.10.100 dev eth0 onlink 
10.10.0.0/21 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.1.200 
125.125.10.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 125.125.10.31
192.168.56.0/21 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.60.101
```

Comment: please also post `ip r l` from the board that looses connection...

Comment: here is it, thats the config while it's connected. I dont know if it changes since I made a simple script that reboots the board any time the gateway is unreachable. 

`default via 125.125.10.100 dev eth0 onlink 10.10.0.0/21 
dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.1.200 125.125.10.0/24 
dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 125.125.10.31 192.168.56.0/21 
dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.60.101`

Comment: Edit your question and add this info..

Comment: You are using `onlink` to make the traffic assigned by you additional ip addresses use `125.125.10.100` as your gateway right?. I would bet here on arp problems, since you are using this kind of gateway(`onlink` is usually assigned to gateways that do not obey the same subnet limitation), and your gateway could be blocking multiple ips on the same mac address of your rpi. I'm just guessing... And have no concrete proof other than my experience with routers and switches :P

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort, I'll be looking into it and I'll be asking the network managers if this could cause the problems.

Comment: Hi. Got your issue solved?

Comment: Hello dear friend, since I didn't have support from on the remote location I couldn't investigate the problem. What I did was simply create a shell script on crontab that checks the gateways each minute and reboots the board if the IP addresses are not reachable. Do you got any suggestions for multiple IP addrs this case? Changing the network interfaces configurations could solve the issue?

Comment: Removing the `onlink` from your default route could solve the issue...